# Resilience4j 2 and retrofit - what happened to the resilience4j-retrofit module?

Tags: retrofit, resilience4j

In Resilience4j 2 the retrofit module got removed (still present as reslience4j-retrofit). Does anyone know if it got replaced by an external module? Are users of retrofit supposed to write and maintain the respective call adapter themselves? Should there now be a more generic way that was not present before?

1.7 tag with the module:
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/tree/1.7/resilience4j-retrofit
https://resilience4j.readme.io/v1.7.0/docs/retrofit

v 2.0.0 version documentation already does not have the module anymore:
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs
while the 2.0 tag still seems to include it:
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/tree/2.0/resilience4j-retrofit

but in master that is also gone:
https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/tree/master/

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/